# How do you set server specific ENV values in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, web-server, virtualhost, environment-variables

I am starting a project that uses environment variables to set the database connection and a couple other things. (They didn't want to use configuration files since people are careless and overwrite them).

Anyway, I am using nginx and while [it supports env](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#env) - it doesn't seem to [support it well enough](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,7124,7124). You can't set the env values on a [per-server block basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735916/nginx-and-environment-variables-from-configuration-file). In other words, this won't work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain;
    env FOO = "bar";
}
```

You must do this:

```
env FOO = "bar";

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain;
    }
}
```

Which means that I can't have vhost-specific values. So I must create a whole vhost config for each site and only activate the one I want at the moment so that the value is set correctly.

**Is there any way to work around this?**

Comment: Isn't the nginx config just as susceptible to overwriting as the application's config?  What module is it using to feed requests to the application?

Comment: @ShaneMadden, the nginx config isn't part of the project but must be created on each server manually. So it won't be overwritten. What I posted isn' the full configs - we are also just using standard `fastcgi_pass` to forward the request to ruby/php.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out that if you are using fastcgi you can get around this by passing the values from [fastcgi_param](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_param).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain;

    # Pass PHP scripts to php-fastcgi listening on port 9000
    location ~ path/to/it {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param FOO "bar";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I was about to suggest.  Beat me to it!  (I'm out of votes for today, I'll upvote this answer in a bit)

Comment: @ShaneMadden perhaps you could help [me with this](http://serverfault.com/questions/351710/how-do-you-conditionally-include-files-in-nginx-vhost).

Comment: Is there any way to set `server_name` dynamically, though? Since it's a virtual host running on OS X, the nginx host has a different IP, so it doesn't resolve.